# How to populate html datatable from a json formatted object in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, datatables, laravel-8

I am having trouble in accessing data from a json object:

json object comes from datatabase:

```
{
   "status":200,
   "remarks":[
      {
         "supplier_id":"2020111",
         "supplier_name":"John Doe",
         "contact_number":"sdfsdfsd",
         "date_entry":"2020-11-05 10:04:44"
      },
      {
         "supplier_id":"2020112",
         "supplier_name":"Jerwen Reloz",
         "contact_number":"sd",
         "date_entry":"2020-11-05 10:50:03"
      },
      {
         "supplier_id":"2020113",
         "supplier_name":"Danny Cane",
         "contact_number":"sd",
         "date_entry":"2020-11-05 10:50:07"
      }
   ]
}
```

I just want to populate my `html datatable` with this data, I am trying to read the `datatables` documentations but I cant find the right solution.

Here is my jquery that handles the request:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/supplier-list',
      dataType: 'json',
      encode: true
})
.done(function (data) {
      console.log(data) //the format defined above
      //i want to populate datatable with this data.
});
```

and my html table:

```
    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Supplier ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Date Entry</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Supplier ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Date Entry</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

thank you.

Comment: i am using laravel-8

Answer (score 0):

sorry this is modified version. i tested on jsfiddle

```
var json = {
   "status":200,
   "remarks":[
      {
         "supplier_id":"2020111",
         "supplier_name":"John Doe",
         "contact_number":"sdfsdfsd",
         "date_entry":"2020-11-05 10:04:44"
      },
      {
         "supplier_id":"2020112",
         "supplier_name":"Jerwen Reloz",
         "contact_number":"sd",
         "date_entry":"2020-11-05 10:50:03"
      },
      {
         "supplier_id":"2020113",
         "supplier_name":"Danny Cane",
         "contact_number":"sd",
         "date_entry":"2020-11-05 10:50:07"
      }
   ]
};

console.log(json);
  var row;
   
for(var i=0; i<json['remarks'].length; i++) {
    var array = json['remarks'];
    row +=  " <tr>" +
   "                <td> " + array[i].supplier_id   + "</td>" +
   "                <td> " + array[i].supplier_name   + "</td>" +
   "                <td> " + array[i].contact_number   + "</td>" +
   "                <td> " + array[i].date_entry   + "</td>"+
     "</tr>";
    
}
  var table = 
   " <thead> " +
   "     <tr> " +
   "         <th>Supplier ID</th> " +
   "         <th>Name</th> " +
   "         <th>Contact</th> " +
   "         <th>Date Entry</th> " +
   "     </tr> " +
   " </thead> " +
   " <tbody> " +
   "            <tr> " +    row +  " </tr> " +
   " </tbody> " ;
$('#example1').html(table);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e8g254uh/10/